# What is the purpose of passing a block to enum_for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

According to the official Ruby docs, there are two ways of calling `enum_for`:

```
enum_for(method = :each, *args) → enum
enum_for(method = :each, *args){|*args| block} → enum
```

I feel like I have a pretty good understanding of Ruby's *enumerators* in general. And so I understand what calling `enum_for` without a block does. But I am confused as to what the purpose of calling it with a block is.

The description in the docs, "If a block is given, it will be used to calculate the size of the enumerator without the need to iterate it", isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the example in the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-enum_for), they've set up a method, `repeat`, which will take an enumerable and yield it's values `n` times. So for the array:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

calling `repeat(3)` will yield:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
...
```

So, I have `array` and call `enum = array.repeat(3)`, and now I want to know how many elements are in the `enum`. I could go through and set up a counter:

```
counter = 0; array.repeat(3) { |element| counter += 1 }
```

and know that there are 15 elements in `enum`, or being a not-computer and having prior knowledge about what `repeat` is doing, I could just say `array.size * 3` and get 15.

But that's all overkill, because `Enumerator` has a [`size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-size) method, so it'd be nice if I could just say `enum.size`. However, size just returns `nil`, because it can't calculate the size lazily, so I'd have to use `count` which is just going to iterate through and count the elements like our naive solution. I can tell `size` how to lazily calculate the size, though, by passing the block to `enum_for` (clipped from the docs)

```
to_enum(__method__, n) do # __method__ is :repeat here
  sz = size     # Call size and multiply by n...
  sz * n if sz  # but return nil if size itself is nil
end
```

and now it behaves like our second method. For a use case like this, it may seem like only a marginal gain, but if I'm repeating a 1,000 element array 1 million times? Or what if my enum is hitting an external service, or doing any number of expensive computations? this small optimization could save quite a few cycles and avoid unnecessary work when all you wanted was a total.

Comment: _"... have to iterate through and count the elements"_ – that's what `count` does. `size` just returns `nil` if you don't provide a block.